# how to check if string matches regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

in java I simply make:

```
boolean match = string.matches("\\d{2}-\\d{2}");
```

how do I make this in javascript?

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp("\\d{2}-\\d{2}", ""); regex.test(string)`

Comment: !!"22-34".match(/\d{2}-\d{2}/);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript:

```
var inputString = '22-34';
var pattern = /\d{2}-\d{2}/;
var match = pattern.test(inputString); // match will equal true
```

[MDN regular expression reference documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)